# Can a non-degenerate polygon with all sides equal have unequal angles?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons

I have always been hearing that a regular polygon is a polygon with equal sides and equal angles, but I never considered the fact that it may be possible for a polygon with all sides equal but unequal angles. Is this even possible? A lucid example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus

Comment: It's possible for any equilateral polygon except a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Consider a rhombus, or a home plate type shape (an equilateral pentagon with unequal angles), or take six toothpicks and attach them end-to-end in a hexagon and observe that you can change the angles freely.